# Jquery Auto Pop up without clicks, would like some assistance with code

Tags: jquery, html, popup

I would like for the pop up to appear once the page loads, without clicking anything.

Is there any tweak or an auto run action?

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
   var methods = {
      autoclose : function(){
         $.fallr('show', {
            buttons   : {},
            content   : '<p>This is a video</p><iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.mywebsite.com/todayinhistory.html" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
            width     : 560 + 100,
            autoclose : 5000,
            icon      : 'clock'
         });
      },
   };
   $('a[href^="#fallr-"]').click(function(){
      var id = $(this).attr('href').substring(7);
      methods[id].apply(this,[this]);
      return false;
   });
});
```

Currently it is working with button click, but I would like to see if I can make it launch once the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

           var methods = {         

                autoclose : function(){
                    $.fallr('show', {
                        buttons     : {},
                        content     : '<p>This is a video</p><iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.mywebsite.com/todayinhistory.html" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
                         width       : 560 + 100, 
                        autoclose   : 5000,
                        icon        : 'clock'
                    });
                }

            };
            $('a[href^="#fallr-"]').click(function(){
                var id = $(this).attr('href').substring(7);
                methods[id].apply(this,[this]);
                return false;
            });

       //autoload popup
       var autoLoadFallr =methods;
        autoLoadFallr.autoclose();
    });
```